# Checkbox selection and form object do not save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I have a form that includes:

- two checkboxes
- text field to gather email addresses

I am not sure if this is the best design, but the model contains three attributes:

- email_name (type string)
- send_once (type boolean)
- send_anytime (type boolean)

I would like to save the email address if either of the two checkboxes are filled otherwise don't save anything.

Everything appeared to be working as I expected, but once I looked inside the rails console, the signup model was empty.

My log file says this:

```
Started POST "/pages" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-01 16:34:55 -0500
Processing by PagesController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",  "authenticity_token"=>"WChW/OmDPS2Td1D3x/36aCJj7V75FdiAPJ9AQvtAIS4=", "post"=>{"email_address"=>"email@examp.le", "send_once"=>"0", "send_any_time"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Create Signup"}
(0.3ms)  BEGIN
(0.5ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "signups" WHERE "signups"."email_address" = '' LIMIT 1
(0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
Rendered pages/_form.html.erb (3.7ms)
```

How do I  go about this? Currently the model does not save. So, specifically what should the model and the controller look like?

**NOTE:** I am creating a `signup` object inside of the Pages controller (think: newsletter).

*Controller*

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
 def index
  @signup = Signup.new
 end

def create
 @signup = Signup.new(params[:signup])
 respond_to do |format| 
  if @signup.save
    format.html
    #format.js
  else
    format.html {render action: :index}
   end
  end
 end
end
```

*Model*

```
class Signup < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email_address
  # email_regex = come up with something
  validates :email_address, presence: true,
                        #format: {with: email_regex}, uniqueness: {message: 'there can only be one you.'}                                    
end
```

_*form.html.erb*

```
<%= form_for(@signup, as: :post, url: pages_path) do |f| %>
  <% if @signup.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
    <p><%= pluralize(@signup.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</p>
   <ul>
    <% @signup.errors.full_messages.each do |user| %>
    <li><%= user %></li>
    <% end %>
   </ul>
  </div>
 <% end %>

 <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :email_address %><br />
   <%= f.email_field :email_address %>
   <%= f.label :send_once %><br />
   <%= f.check_box :send_once %>
   <%= f.label :send_any_time %><br />
   <%= f.check_box :send_any_time %>

  </div>

  <div class="actions">
   <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your params are being passed in as :post and your create statement is looking for params[:signup].  You either need to change your controller to look for params[:post] or change your form to submit to params[:signup].

```
<%= form_for(@signup, as: :signup, url: pages_path) do |f| %>
```

You'll also want to add a check for whether or not the checkboxes are checked.
Presuming your parameters are:

```
"signup"=>{"email_address"=>"email@examp.le", "send_once"=>"0", "send_any_time"=>"1"}
```

You'll want to do:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
   @signup = Signup.new
  end

  def create
    @signup = Signup.new(params[:signup])
    if @signup.send_once == "1" or @signup.send_any_time == "1" then
      respond_to do |format| 
        if @signup.save
          format.html
        else
          format.html {render action: :index}
        end
      end
    else
      # what do you want to do if they didn't sign up?  redirect somewhere?
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks this was very easy to follow along. I got confused with the `as` option and `method` option.

Comment: It turns out setting the if-statement to a string of "1" instead of true they are boolean type was preventing the record from saving. Very helpful @denise-mauldin nonetheless!