# model saves in console, not from web ui

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I asked this question [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9103824/checkbox-selection-and-form-object-do-not-save) today and from the console, it works as expected. However, when I built my form out to include (e.g. ajax, styles) it does not appear to be saving to the model.

Any ideas where to make my fix?

cheers -

*Signup Model*

```
class Signup < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email_address, :send_once, :send_any_time
  # email_regex = stub it out later
  validates :email_address, presence: true,
                        #format: {with: email_regex},
  uniqueness: {message: 'there can only be one you.'} 
 end
```

*PagesController*

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
 def index
  @signup = Signup.new
  end

 def create
   @signup = Signup.new(params[:signup])
    if @signup.send_once == "1" or @signup.send_any_time == "1"
     respond_to do |format| 
      if @signup.save
       format.js
      else
       format.html {render action: :index}
      end
   end
  else
   #if they don't sign, do something!
  end
 end
end
```

__form.html.erb_

```
<%= form_for(@signup, method:post, as: :signup, url: pages_path, html: {id: "button"}, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <% if @signup.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
    <p><%= pluralize(@signup.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</p>
   <ul>
    <% @signup.errors.full_messages.each do |user| %>
    <li><%= user %></li>
    <% end %>
   </ul>
  </div>
 <% end %>

 <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :email_address %><br />
   <%= f.email_field :email_address %>
   <%= f.label :send_once %><br />
   <%= f.check_box :send_once %>
   <%= f.label :send_any_time %><br />
   <%= f.check_box :send_any_time %>

  </div>

  <div class="actions">
   <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Try basic debug printing. What comes in `params`? What state does `@signup`? To what value that condition is evaluated, etc?

Comment: from my development.log file `  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"NPpMFeByG2U6+yl8sE69lf6qI7HX/4GZmiCstBoB2AE=", "signup"=>{"email_address"=>"hoop@hype.com", "send_once"=>"0", "send_any_time"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Create Signup"}
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this line is your problem:

```
if @signup.send_once == "1" or @signup.send_any_time == "1"
```

By the time the parameters have gone through the model, they're probably `true`, not `"1"`. There's a very subtle difference to these in Ruby and Rails.